# Order of terms in matrix equations

Tags: linear-algebra

The closed-form solution for a linear regression model with least squares is $(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}y$ but I have a hard time deriving it, mostly because of some questions on linear algebra operations.

First we have the least squares formula as:

$    \min\limits_{\beta} (y - X\beta)^{T}(y - X\beta)    $

To find the $\beta$ that minimizes the equation, we take a derivative and set it to $0$:

$    X(y - X\beta) = 0    $

$    X^{T}y - X^{T}X\beta = 0    $

$    X^{T}X\beta = X^{T}y    $

$    \beta = (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}y    $

In Step 2 (out of all 5), how do we know that this should be the order of the derivative and not $(y - X\beta)X = 0$?

Similarly, in Step 3 how do we know that we need to transpose $X$?

I understand it wouldn't work if the order is reversed (Step 2), or if $X$ is not transposed (Step 3), but is the rule "if the dimensions require it, then transpose it", or is there something more formal?

Comment: there are k first order conditions. write/derive them without matrix notation first, then go from there to matrix form.

Comment: Prove everything in https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf , then you'll really know what you're doing.